# UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp and CurlDown with landscape

Tags: iphone, uiimage, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation, page-curl

Please help me find an answer since i searched everywhere in here and many other websites. Am using this code to make the pageCurl effect.

// Start Animation Block

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp
                       forView:[self view] cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
```

// Start Animation Block

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context]; 
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown
                       forView:[self view] cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
```

As you can see above that am using UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown and UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp to iterate between several images in a landscapeRight and landscapeLeft orientation. My question is, will my application be accepted by apple?!

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just based on this code - I don't see any reason why not, You are not accessing any private API. As long as the rest of the app works (doesn't crash...) and you don't violate any of Apple's other rules.